# popbackstack NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment (A) where i use an async task to retrieve a list from the internet.
At the end of the asyncTask(onPostExecute)  i fill my listView.

```
     listView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),list));
```

Now i have another fragment (B).When i click from my ActionBar the fragmen
t B i want to clear the backstack and then replace fragment (A) with (B)

```
   public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
   //clears backstack every time a tab is selected to avoid errors or wrong tab browsing.
    if(context.getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
        context.getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, ((Object) fragment).getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

When i click fragment (B) i get NullpointerException at onPostExcecute of fragment A.So my Questions are ,1)when popbackstack is called the compiler tries to redraw the whole previews fragment?2)How to just clear the fragmentManager and replace the existing fragment with a new one?

Comment: You need to fix your if statement first of all. Not enough brackets.

Comment: i dont think so...is it better now?

Comment: Oh. Yes, if that's what you intended. Always use brackets, even if you only have one line.

Comment: i will have that in mind thx :)

Comment: Edited the whole post to make it more clear

Comment: Any ideas?So far i forced the back button to close the program cause i cant find the solution